# Где сейчас достать корпус коротких текстов RuTweetCorp, который собран Ю.Рубцовой?

Tags: машинное-обучение

[image: сайт недоступен]

Или что-то похожее русскоязычное для обучения модели есть?
Может кто чем-нибудь поделиться

Comment: А гуглить не пробовали по "RuTweetCorp"? Там много разных ссылок вылазит, может где и оригинальный датасет скопирован, а не только его переработка лежит.